# Can't able to run Tomcat server with broadleaf in maven

Tags: tomcat

I have run basic demo application it shows the following error:

> nested exception is **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:** Name [jdbc/web] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

My context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context sessionCookieName="JSESSIONIDADMIN">

    <!-- disable session persistence -->
    <Manager pathname="" />
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/web"
             global="jdbc/web"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany-community</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecommerce-website</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <name>core</name>
    <description>Customizations And Extensions For Broadleaf Commerce Services And Entities</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <rootPath>${basedir}</rootPath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-framework</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-profile</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-menu</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-sample-payment-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you add Resource settings of GlobalNamingResources in server.xml? If not, you should add the settings.

For example:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
  ...
  <Resource name="jdbc/web"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="test"
            password="test"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@***.***.***.***:1521:orcl" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Or change the content of context.xml, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/web"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="test"
            password="test"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@***.***.***.***:1521:orcl" />
</Context>
```

Or remove the Resource tag from context.xml if the application doesn't need to access to DB.

Comment: did that still it is throwing the following error:

[ERROR] 11:36:38 **ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException**: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager' while setting bean property 'persistenceUnitManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed;